# Difference between helper files and lib files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What exactly is the difference between `helper` files and `lib` files in rails? When should these files be used appropriately?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Helpers in Rails are used to organize *helpers* in the views. So you can create a method in some helper module, say:

```
module SomeModule
 def markdown(string)
   #some behaviuor
 end
end
```

and then use it in the view: `markdown("Hello world")`.

The **Lib** folder should keep the parts of your code that are not completely relevant to models, controller, helpers or views. Say you implement your own web crawler in separate class. It is better to keep it in `lib/my_crawler.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

helpers is a mixins (modules) otherwise in /lib you can place classes and whole libraries